# Why am I getting a syntax error from my alias if I don't re-source my bash_profile?

Tags: bash

This alias is giving me trouble:

```
alias dm="git diff master > $dl && subl $dl"
```

If I run `source ~/.bash_profile`, then it works. But if I just open the terminal and run `dm` without sourcing first, I get:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

If I restart the terminal after sourcing, it doesn't work again. What's the issue here? `$dl` is this, defined near the end of bash_profile:

```
export dl=~/"Desktop/Diffs/today.diff"
```

(I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. Unlikely relevant, but even so.)

Comment: Why are you using an alias for this rather than a function to start with?

Comment: `dm() { git diff master >"$dl" && subl "$dl" "$@"; }` is the function equivalent to this alias, which should generally be preferred -- functions provide considerably more flexibility around argument handling and flow control.

Comment: (for instance, you could use `$1` to override `$dl` if you wanted to in a function, but have no direct access to arguments in an alias).

Comment: ...you could also add error-checking in a function: `dm() { if [[ $dl ]]; then git diff master >"$dl" && subl "$dl" "$@"; else echo 'ERROR: dl variable not defined' >&2; return 1; fi; }`

Comment: ...btw, is `$dl` just a temporary file? If so, and `subl` can read from a pipe, you may not even need it: `dm() { subl <(git diff master); }`

Comment: Ha I know that it could be a function and that functions have greater flexibility, it was a small thing and I figured an alias was sufficient. It should be noted that I actually get the same error in the function form, though, when I tried it previously, to see if that worked when this didn't.

Comment: As an explanation for that -- the function form always defers variable expansions, whereas whether that happens for aliases varies with the quoting type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `dl` is properly empty when your alias is defined. And it will expand to:

```
alias dm="git diff master >  && subl "
```

Using single quotes instead of double quotes will let the variable expansion happen when the alias is used:

```
alias dm='git diff master > "$dl" && subl "$dl"'
```

Now the `dl` variable is expanded when `dm` is typed on the command line:

```
% dl=hello
% dm -> git diff master > hello && subl hello
% dl=world
% dm -> git diff master > world && subl world
```

Also note that I added quotes around `$dl` to avoid word splitting and globbing.

You might consider using a function instead of an alias, IMO aliases are for stuff like adding color to ls, grep etc...

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

While functions are for running more complex command:

```
dm() {
  git diff master > "$dl"
  subl "$dl"
 }
```

BTW. Many commands support the `-` flag which tells that the input is comming from stdin, so the following might work:

```
 dm() {
   git diff master | subl -
 }
```

Comment: A good answer, but I'd argue that replacing the alias with a function would be even better.

Comment: `git diff master | subl /dev/stdin` or `subl <(git diff master)` might also be worth consideration, if `-` isn't explicitly handled (and, of course, if `subl` can handle FIFOs rather than seekable files for input).

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have defined `dl` towards the end of the `.bash_profile` script. Does this mean that `dl` is exported after your `dm` alias?

Try swapping the two commands around so `dl` is exported first, then when your `dm` alias is set, it will inherit the `dl` variable.

The reason why it works after sourcing is because the initial terminal log in will source the `dl` variable, and then your manual `source` will then reset the alias with the `dl` variable that was defined shortly before.